# Summing a Case Statement with a check for Value in Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a report that I am working on, the report has a few parameters passed to it. One of them is a string of UserIds that are operated by commas. These are split and sent into a table variable. In side of my query I need to be able to sum values. In a few of these Sums I need to by case add this value to the sum and in another case not add to it. The code looks something like this...

```
    SELECT 
        TrnId,
        TrnCode,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyUseId in (select UseId From @Table) then TotalPremium else 0 end)) as Value
        AnotherColumn
    FROM SomeTableJoinedOnOtherThings
```

The issue that I am having is this... "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." This is, I assume, from the check for the IN table.

I have another report just like this except that I am only doing the check on a parameter that I pass the query.

```
    (CASE PolicyUseId when @UseId then PriceColumn else 0 end)
```

This Query works and does all the calculations correctly. I am not exactly sure how else to get the totals correct without this case statement in the select line as I need to pull 2 sets of data a decide how to add them in the select unfortunately. Any Advice would be great.

Comment: If you remove the `SUM`, did it works?...how about doing a CTE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need the aggregation at all:

```
SELECT TrnId, TrnCode,
       (CASE WHEN PolicyUseId in (select UseId From @Table) then TotalPremium else 0 end) as Value
       AnotherColumn
FROM SomeTableJoinedOnOtherThings;
```

If you do need aggregation, you need a `GROUP BY`.  And then `LEFT JOIN` will work -- assuming you have no duplicates in `@Table`:

```
SELECT TrnId, TrnCode,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tt.UseId IS NOT NULL THEN TotalPremium ELSE 0 END) as Value,
       AnotherColumn
FROM SomeTableJoinedOnOtherThings t LEFT JOIN
     @Table tt
     ON t.PolicyUseId = tt.UseId
GROUP BY TrnId, TrnCode, AnotherColumn;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This made the Query much more digestible in the long run as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't aggregrate against a subquery.

Perhaps LEFT OUTER JOIN @table in your example to the PolicyUseId field's table on that field? Then check if UseId is NULL in the CASE?